# how to fix this error, NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed , it return many times?

Tags: flutter, ocr

I used package

`google_mlkit_text_recognition`

for scan image

in this methode in viewModel :

```
bool _isPrespection = false;
  bool get isPrespect => _isPrespection;
  Future<void> recognizingText(XFile? images) async {
    final inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(images!.path);
    final textRecognizer = TextRecognizer();
    final recognizedText = await textRecognizer.processImage(inputImage);
    textRecognizer.close();
 
    var resulttext = '';
    for (TextBlock block in recognizedText.blocks) {
      for (TextLine line in block.lines) {
        resulttext = "$resulttext  ${line.text}";
      }
    }
    print(resulttext);
   
  }
```

when call this methode in view  (statlessWidget) here

```
var uploadImageModel =
        Provider.of<uploaPrespectionViewmodelProvider>(context);
      uploadImageModel.recognizingText(images);
```

return this error:

```
 NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 42116(1410KB) AllocSpace objects, 12(296KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 4935KB/9871KB, paused 159us total 122.025ms
```

and always keep repeating until the application stops.

thanks